# SQLite sort special characters alphabetically

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an application that is used to teach people French. When I try to sort some French words do not end up where I intended them to be, for example:

- Aller
- Boire
- En
- Être
- Vouloir

Will be sorted in the following order:

- Aller
- Boire
- En
- Vouloir
- Être

The SQL statement I'm currently using is:

```
SELECT name, assignment_id FROM GrammarAssignments ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE
```

Comment: is the same output when you enter some different name. ex enter this name : a,b,d,v tell me what output you getting .

Comment: Sorry, had some faults in my example. Fixed it now.

Comment: ok .try it and get back to me

Comment: The result would be: a, b, d, v obviously. But my problem is with special characters like é. So I'm getting: A, B, E, V, É instead of A, B, E, É, V.

Comment: then you have to specify each symbolic to char it may run perfact .

Comment: this has been discussed, and basically, it is not possible. one suggestion is to store a diacritic-free version in another column and use that column for sorting

Comment: mean if your symbol like @ then you have to specify @=A OR @=a. get it ?

Comment: its again same .you get other string and store into different column and sorting it, and base on that you can retrieve your actual value .

Comment: @njzk2 The extra column is what my current implementation is. I was just hoping there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: the solution is about COLLATE, but i am pretty sure it doesn't work in android (i have seen suggestion of COLLATE LOCALIZED or UNICODE, but not tested it)

Comment: @njzk2 COLLATE LOCALIZED seems to crash the app, maybe the SQLite version is too old in Android? Same for UNICODE.

Comment: @JonKnoops: Please don't keep the error messages a secret.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case some one else comes across this post, I ran into the same issue and tested it. The below should do the trick of sorting depending on the locale as well as sorting case insensitive.

```
SELECT name, assignment_id FROM GrammarAssignments ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Android's [SQLite implementation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) has the `LOCALIZED` and `UNICODE` collations for this.

See the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) for how to apply collations to table columns and SQL expressions.

Comment: Could you give me an example?