# French Language ABC Order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sqlite

I am building a web application using Javascript, HTML, and CSS. I have a table called `categories` I am pulling from my SQLite database called `Main Database`. The words are in french and the problem I am seeing is that letters with accents on top get sent to the bottom of the list instead of next to the normal letter they should be with.

[image]

JavaScript:

```
function listMainSymptomsDb(tx) {
    var category = getUrlVars().category;
    tx.executeSql("SELECT Main_Symptom, max(Add_Symptom) AS   
   `firstAddSymptom` from `Main Database` WHERE Category='" + category + "' 
    GROUP BY `Main_Symptom`",[],txSuccessListMainSymptoms);
```

Can anyone recommend a way I can order my letters correctly?

Comment: Looks like SQLite is to blame here, unless there's an additional sorting step (in Javascript) you haven't shown. This question has links to SQLite locale/collation details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248601/sqlite-sort-special-characters-alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help from this [source](http://lunarbovine.com/blog/2013/08/sorting-french-accented-characters-in-javascript/):

```
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
 fruits.push("étudiant");
 fruits.push("éléphant");
 fruits.push("à l'heure");

 function frsort(a,b) 
 {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
 }
 alert(fruits.sort(frsort));
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmtmnupe/4/)**

Comment: Thank you for this code. I am not a javascript pro by any means and am actually a beginner.. I tried implementing the code but unfortunately nothing it is still at the bottom. Is there something I am doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Lo39n64d/

Comment: @chronotrigga:- Its not going to work in Fiddle as you are trying to get the data from the database. So my suggestion is get the data from the database into an array. And then you can use the above method.

Comment: I added it into my actual javascript code -- the problem is if I put the actual words into an array, I will lose the UrlVars correct? My category names, when clicked, go to the next page.

Comment: @chronotrigga:- Certainly you do, so my point is you need to first execute the query and then get the result of that query into an array. And once you get the result into an array you can use the above method to get them sorted.